# Hyperledger Installation Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, failed-installation

I am trying to install hyperledger fabric development environment. While starting the network after generation of needed certificates, I am getting the following error on my Mac:

```
Failed loading private key [ee80248539b4c020b7004fb9ab1c5761ce41124eda7a7e29c06460ee51ca2315]: [open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/ee80248539b4c020b7004fb9ab1c5761ce41124eda7a7e29c06460ee51ca2315_sk: permission denied].

Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

It obviously shows that your configuration about the certification and keystore is not correct. Try to check that whether the key material your posted above is exist or not. And reconfig your network according to your crypto generation file.